# Questions regarding Vector Array of Structs

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I made a post about this yesterday, but it is a fairly different question. Not sure if I should make a new question or just reply to the old one but here goes.

Basically I am setting up my vector array of structs as follows..

```
class Debugger : public Ogre::SimpleRenderable
{
    struct DebugVertex
    {
        Ogre::Vector3 v;
        unsigned int color;
    };

    typedef std::vector<DebugVertex> Buffer;

protected:

    Buffer              mLineBuffer;
```

The problem is occuring in the code for example...

mLineBuffer.reserve(128); reports it is not a member of Debugger::DebugVertex. This holds true with all vector operations such as reserve, empty, ptr, size, etc. They all exist but it is looking for them in the struct. How am I supposed to access these?

Comment: what if you remove the typedef and declare directly: std::vector<DebugVertex> mLineBuffer

Comment: Can you show some relevant diagnostic output?

Comment: Can you show us how you are trying to do `reserve`?

Comment: Here is the header/source file http://ampaste.net/m344006a7 - http://ampaste.net/m41c7fa65

Comment: Did you try adding `#include <vector>`?

Comment: @Brett: Please update the question to include the relevant code rather than using paste sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the exact compiler error?  My guess is that `DebugVertex` does not conform to the interface required for inclusion in STL containers like `std::vector`, possibly because `Ogre::Vector3` needs work.

Can you include the declaration for `Ogre::Vector3`?

Comment: Well for some reason I just recompiled without changing anything (to bring back up the errors) and it compiled fine minus a couple of simple errors. I don't know what caused them before, but for some reason they are gone. I am wondering though, utArray (what I am replacing with vector) used mLineBuffer.ptr(); I can't find an equivalent function in vector, is there not one?

Comment: @Brett: What did utArray's ptr method do?  You may just be looking for `&mLineBuffer[0]`, if my guess is correct that ptr returns a pointer to the internal array.

Comment: typedef T           *Pointer;
Pointer     m_data;
UT_INLINE Pointer      ptr(void)                { return m_data; }

Answer (score 1):

Your typedef using a private struct, any code outside the Debugger class trying to use it will not compile.

std::vector is not part of your class...

Either make std::vector<DebugVertex> a friend class (didn't test, have to check) or simply make your structure public.